# window is not closing in php javascript

Tags: javascript, php

close function is not working in php

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        $to = "mailid@domain.com";
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $no = $_POST['number'];
        $headers = "Details of: $email";
        $headers = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $subject = "You got the details of $email";
        $body="email: $email, phne: $no";
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
        echo"<script>window.close()</script>";}
```

// close fn **strong text**is not working

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary*
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement 
are not useful to other readers. See: 
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the window.close() on a Javascript event.
For example the submit of that form you use to send the email.